# Ansible Playbook skip some play on multiple play playbook file

Tags: ansible

I have an ansible playbook YAML file which contains 3 plays.

The first play and the third play run on localhost but the second play runs on remote machine as you can see an example below:

```
- name: Play1
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ... task here

- name: Play2
  hosts: remote_host
  tasks:
    - ... task here

- name: Play3
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ... task here
```

I found that, on the first run, Ansible Playbook executes `Play1` and `Play3` and skips `Play2`. Then, I try to run again, it executes all of them correctly.

What is wrong here?

Comment: What does it mean "Ansible skips `Play2`"? Does it print `Play2... skipping` or what? Include the log (replace tasks with `- debug:`) and your inventory file.

Comment: Can you show the full task as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, at `Play2`, I use ec2 inventor like `tag_Name_my_machine` but this instance was not created yet, because it would be created at `Play1`'s task.

Once `Play1` finished, it will run `Play2` but no host found so it silently skip this play.

The solution is to create dynamic inventor and manually register at `Play1`'s tasks:

Playbook may look like this:

```
- name: Play1
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Launch new ec2 instance
      register: ec2
      ec2: ...
    - name: create dynamic group
      add_host:
        name: "{{ ec2.instances[0].private_ip }}"
        group: host_dynamic_lastec2_created

- name: Play2
  user: ...
  hosts: host_dynamic_lastec2_created
  become: yes
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  tasks:
    - name: do something
      shell: ...

- name: Play3
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - ... task here
```